# delete pods forcefully kubernetes API

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking for an option in kubernetes API by which I can delete the running pod forcefully. In short I am searching API for the below command-
`kubectl delete pod --grace-period=0 --force <pod_name>`.
I was referring kube API here-
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#delete-pod-v1-core

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I run your command `kubectl delete pod --grace-period=0 --force <pod_name> --v 10` and notice the output logs and found following

```
$ curl -k -v -XDELETE  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/security-context-demo --data '{"gracePeriodSeconds":0,"propagationPolicy":"Background"}'
```